# How to update the code from Angular 1.5 to Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

Is there any easier way  to do it or I need to start from scratch.

Comment: did you ever google this? The [first result](https://vsavkin.com/migrating-angular-1-applications-to-angular-2-in-5-simple-steps-40621800a25b) has a good explanation

Answer (score 5):

Start from scratch. They are very different frameworks.